# Что делать с полностью заимствованными ответами с указанием источника?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, нытьё

Есть хороший полный развернутый ответ: 
[React.js. Когда использовать компонент?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618640/react-js-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/618655#618655)
UPD: Ответ на текущий момент удален.

Все бы ничего, но это полная копипаста слово в слово из стороннего источника, источник при этом в конце ответа указан, ответ не был оформлен как цитата. Никаких пояснений к цитате тоже нет, то есть ответ-голая цитата.

Как относится сообщество к таким ответам?

Comment: Обернул все под шумок в цитату ;-)

Comment: @Arhad зачем вы хотите сделать это голосованием? Разве Утка привел варианты пронумерованых ответов? Пока что тут просто обсуждение.

Comment: Зависит от того, под какой лицензией публикуются материалы в стороннем источнике. Если лицензия позволяет так делать, почему бы и нет. Пересказывать своими словами хорошо, но порой долго. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, так как ответ на текущий момент удален, то пожалуй в вопросе не хватает важных нюансов, превращающих лично для меня ответ в невалидный, я их добавил. Понятно что цитирование необходимо, но насколько допустим ответ состоящий из одной лишь большой цитаты? Причем это не цитата какого-то важного куска кода а цитата рассуждений на тему

Comment: связанный (отличающийся) вопрос: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/137096)

Comment: @jfs, это не является плагиатом, то есть сознательной копипастой без указания источника, так что это отличающийся вопрос

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму к чему вы это написали? Мой комментарий явно слово "отличающийся" уже содержит специально для людей, которые слово "связанный" как "идентичный" (ошибочно) воспринимают.

Answer (score 10):

Давайте разбираться по уровням.

Хороший полезный ответ достоин плюса. Плохой и неправильный - минуса. Невалидный  - удаления. По ссылке ответ хороший? Если да - плюс.

Следующий уровень, хотим ли мы поощрить постера за этот ответ. Критерии качества ответа нам говорят, что надо приводить цитаты, т.к. ссылка может "умереть". Вероятно можно поставить плюс как минимум за то что постер нашел и привел релевантный фрагмент. Минус поставить за то что проделал недостаточно большую работу и не переписал своими словами?

В общем, минус тут ставить не за что. Ответ полезен.

#### А вот что стоит обсуждения - размер цитаты и разрешение от автора/источника ее делать. Какова политика SO в этом направлении?

Comment: ну начнем с того, что сначала в ответе даже оформления как цитаты не было, типа "большой текст", а потом "взято отсюда", поэтому в изначальном виде мне кажется ответ минуса достоин.

Comment: Ну и плюс лично мой минус за то что насколько я могу судить по ответам автора он врядли в состоянии понять то что скопипастил (т.е. он просто погуглил за автора, но погуглил не конкретное api а некоторые общие соображения). Но это мои личные соображения на минус к конкретному посту, мне интересен общий подход а не оценка конкретного поста.

Comment: Ну и плюс лично для меня ответ-цитата даже без вводной мало отличается от ответа голой ссылкой, с точки зрения so может и отличается тем что ссылка может протухнуть относительно ответа, для меня как разработчика - нет

Comment: Ответ, содержащий новый вопрос для обсуждения?

Comment: Где-то тут уже обсуждались юридические аспекты копи-пасты, надо поискать на Мете.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму: состояние мозга автора вопроса не имеет значения (если бот (в основном) полезные ответы будет публиковать, то только плюс). *Голосование должно зависеть только от содержимого ответа*, а не кто автор, насколько автор понимает написанное в вашем представлении итд. Если содержимое плагиат или как-то по-другому нарушает лицензию, то следует тревогу поднять (чтобы ответ поправить, чтобы он требованиям лицензии отвечал или вообще удалить). Только ссылка хуже, так как практика показывает: ссылки умирают, web archive тормозит и комментарии/голоса лучше на одном сайте копить...

Comment: ...[продолжение] Лучше кратко изложить суть решения и ссылку на подробности отставить.

Comment: @jfs, я понимаю что в сферическом вакууме - не должно. Это мой личный минус "не нравится" и все, минусы ставлю где хочу, законом не запрещено. Поэтому в основном вопросе я стараюсь затронуть объективную составляющую а не мое личное недовольство. Объективная составляющая: "ответ из одной голой цитаты не оформленной как цитата. Что делать?"

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму: если вы ставите минус заведомо полезным ответам, то вы наносите вред сайту (если вы не в "сферическом вакууме"  голосуете). Если вы хвалитесь ещё "минусы ставлю где хочу", то вы и других вдохновляете "личные минусы" ставить. Как вы считаете, что нужно делать с участниками, которые сознательно продолжают вред сайту наносить, поощряя других также поступать? 2- про "объективную составляющую" я выше написал: тревога/править/удалить.

Comment: @jfs, я не нарушаю правила сайта. Если нарушаю можно меня забанить, буду только рад, вот только Вы не модератор. То что видение того что полезно у меня отличается от общепринятого, я не отрицаю. Вот лично Вы например тоже не весь в белом, недавно устраивали войну правок на вопрос Шиманского на мете, что так же является грубым нарушением общепринятого подхода. Этот ответ на мой взгляд является настолько же заведомо полезным как ответ-голая ссылка, вот и все.

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму фраза "заведомо полезным" в моём комментарии означает "заведомо полезным" *по вашему мнению* (насколько ответ помогает решать проблему из вопроса). Не нужно лозейки в правилах искать: сайт рассчитан, что большинство людей нормальные ("assume good faith", "be nice") и не требуется бюрократия из тысячи томов, чтобы сайтом пользоваться. Если вы сознательно вредите (то есть вы знаете что вред наносите), то не важно прописаны конкретные действия в каких-то правилах или нет.

Comment: @jfs, я считаю что приношу пользу. Я прекрасно осознаю что по вашему мнению я врежу, и мне на это пока плевать. Собственно я создал вопрос чтобы понимать насколько мнение сообщества (Вы - часть сообщества, но кажется завели привычку говорить от имени всего сообщества), чтобы понять вдруг мне надо перестать на это плевать или перестать быть частью сообщества. Все просто.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму: я не лично вас обсуждаю (это не моё дело), а конкретное поведение: "личные минусы" (вы сказали:  *"Это мой личный минус "не нравится" и все, минусы ставлю где хочу, законом не запрещено"*. Я сказал: *"если вы ставите минус заведомо полезным [по вашему мнению] ответам, то вы наносите вред сайту"* (слово "вы" здесь означает любой кто таким поведением занимается--персонально вас я не обсуждаю, я  не модератор--я обсуждаю какое поведение считается допустимым на сайте, а какое нет). Старайтесь на личности не переходить и конструктивно отвечать.

Comment: @jfs, ок, простите за переход на личности, я думал что "вы" - адресовано лично мне. Я думаю Вы можете обсудить это отдельным вопросом на мете а не здесь в комментариях.

Answer (score 8):

Если ответ целиком состоит из чужого текста, как насчёт того, чтобы **отметить его общим**?

Это не требование и не правило — просто рекомендация. Я бы так поступил, мне это кажется честным.

Comment: Вряд ли этому совету будут следовать те, кому мало репутации. Ответ найти, скопировать, отформатировать -- а потом вдруг сделать общим. Возможно, некоторые и не будут начинать.

Comment: Т. е. если перевёл с английского, то свой, а если скомпоновал из статей на русском, то общий? Не согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy если проанализировал пачку статей, выделил суть из каждой и скомпоновал в ответ — то свой. Работа же проделана! Обычно при этом ещё комментарии составителя добавляются. А вот если прямо Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V – тогда общий.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Мне кажется это использование отметки как "общий" не по назначению (просто для того, чтобы репутация не капала). Как общий имхо надо отмечать, если есть желание чтобы могли и другие вносить правки, значительно меняющие содержимое.

Answer (score 4):

1. Составлять ответ из других источников можно. Это даже в рекомендации к исправлению ответа-ссылки написано.
2. Указать источник нужно. Не важно, в начале или в конце. Если человек не дочитал ответ до конца, чтобы увидеть ссылку, то ему абсолютно всё равно, откуда это взято. Скопипастил кусок кода к себе и пошёл дальше. И ссылку не оставил.
3. Ставить весь ответ цитатой не нужно. Это ухудшает читаемость и ничего не даёт. Плюс, см. прошлый пункт.
4. Если придёт автор оригинального поста и опубликует это сам, ответ следует удалить или почистить, оставив только свои дополнения.
5. Впрочем, [иногда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615736/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/615756#comment851670_615756) автор не против.

Comment: Соглашусь: у нас тут база знаний, а не мерило знаний конкретного участника. Если ответ полезный и тем более если он помог автору, то однозначно достоин плюса, даже если отвечающий сам не до конца понял свой ответ.

Comment: "Если придёт автор оригинального поста и опубликует это сам, ответ следует удалить или почистить, оставив только свои дополнения" зачем удалять?

Comment: @Suvitruf, чтобы одна и та же информация не дублировалась. Логично же, что у автора приоритет в этом плане.

Comment: @Qwertiy чтоб не дублировалось, не нужно дублировать ответ. Я не вижу никакого приоритета. Его и так уже указали в источнике. Если ему есть, что добавить - пожалуйста. Но ответ удалять не надо.

Comment: @Suvitruf, удалить только в случае дублирования.

Comment: @Qwertiy если сейчас придёт автор ответа с SOen и оставит свой ответ под каким-то faq вопросом, скопированным с enSO и жутко заплюсованным, то нужно удалить ответ?

Comment: @Suvitruf, ты копипастишь чей-то ответ с форума без изменений. Автор того ответа приходит сюда и публикует то же самое сам. Получается два одинаковых ответа - твой и авторский. Какой из них по-твоему надо удалить?

Comment: @Qwertiy тот, что позже. Я тут, кстати, не раз видел ответы с ссылками на мой блог с указанием источника, но не бежал публиковать "авторский" ответ. Человек, как минимум, нашёл блог/форум и т.п. Сам факт авторства не даёт мне привилегий)

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну, возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Так как функционал сайта позволяет вносить правки в чужие ответы, то лично я бы произвел правку ответа, добавив теги цитаты, после чего судил бы этот ответ исходя только из того, насколько этот ответ в итоге правилен, полезен и так далее.

Ставить минус человеку за то, что он, возможно, просто забыл оформить цитату как цитату, или же просто не знал, что это лучше делать, стоило бы в том случае, если не было возможности самостоятельно поправить чужой ответ, то есть как бы показать автору минусом (а опционально - и прокомментировать его ответ / написать личным сообщением), что цитаты нужно выделять. Но если есть возможность правки, то стоит наверное все-таки показывать это не минусом, а правкой, согласитесь.

Comment: Вы путаете комментарий и ответ. Ответ — это то, что вы опубликовали здесь. Комментарий я вам сейчас пишу. :)

Comment: `написать личным сообщением` — На StackOverflow [нет личных сообщений](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441/208074).

Comment: Правильный подход -- ставить плюсы и минусы **вопросу/ответу**, а не человеку (хотя, наверное 90 % посетителей (в т.ч. и участников) сайта, понять этого не в состоянии и оценивают автора)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, я понимаю, просто уже не стал лишний раз править комментарий. Но спасибо.

Comment: @Arhad, да, спасибо, но так или иначе я имел ввиду, что это можно как-то напрямую автору ответа озвучить, хоть в комментарии к его ответу, хоть отправив ему по указанным у него контактным данным сообщение.

Comment: Не считаю нужным выделять как цитату, так что не ставлю ни плюс, ни минус, поскольку с остальным согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати да, если весь текст заимствован, то форматирование цитатой не добавляет смысла. С тем же успехом можно было бы весь текст сделать полужирным и курсивом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну так вроде речь вообще изначально не о добавлении смысла в ответ, а об уважении к авторским правам, разве нет?

Answer (score 0):

Удивительно, что ответ под гнётом был удалён. К счастью, там набралось голосов и ответ был восстановлен.

1. Отвечает ли на вопрос? Да. Тогда не важно, скопирован он или нет.
2. У нас куча скопированных ответов с SOen. Почему никто на них не наезжает?
3. Про ссылки в комментариях уже была тема. У нас тут очень много тех, оказывается, кто считает, что, цитирую "если не можете дать ответ, то и не оставляйте в комментариях ссылку".
4. Ну и уж точно не нужно всё цитатами оформлять - указания источника в конце ответа будет достаточно.

Единственная проблема - лицензия. С SOen можно копировать без проблем, т.к. лицензия позволяет. Если вы копируете ответ с чужого блога, то, если там лицензия не указана вовсе, это означает, по умолчанию, что распространять информацию нельзя.

Answer (score -3):

Копипаста **не нужна**. Достаточно ссылки в комментариях.

Проблема «умирания» ссылок может быть решена их архивированием с помощью сервиса [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

**P. S.:** Действительно полезный материал **можно пересказать своими словами**. Это позволяет:

- во-первых, упростить подачу материала (отношение к тексту и требования при написании большой статьи и маленького ответа разные),
- во-вторых, избавиться от формального языка, используемого в статьях,
- в-третьих, вычленить действительно нужное и главное.

Comment: на многие вопросы можно ответить ссылкой, не публиковать ответы совсем?

Comment: @Bald, перескажите текст своими словами. Тем более сейчас он звучит слишком «официально». У нас же сайт не статей-руководств, а ответов по сути.

Comment: Wayback Machine не сохраняет многие вещи. Да и цель SO все-таки не собрать коллекцию ссылок на любой вопрос (этим занимается Яндекс и Google), а собрать базу вопросов и ответов.

Comment: если честно я не вижу смысла *переписывать* хороший во всех смыслах материал. единственное что действительно может быть проблемой так это не против ли *переводчик* использования его материала

Comment: @Kromster, вот потому я и сказал про пересказ. С одной стороны не копипаста, с другой — будет проще воспринимать информацию, ведь отношение к тексту при написании большой статьи и маленького ответа разные.

Comment: @Bald, а перевод это не копипаста. Даже Гражданский Кодекс признаёт переводчиков полноценными авторами (пусть и перевода).

Comment: @Bald, добавил уточнение в ответ.

Comment: В некоторых случаях действительно бывает необходимо сделать то что Вы предлагаете, но далеко не всегда. в данном конкретном случае не вижу причин переписывать ответ. как я уже сказал вопрос остается только в правомерности

Comment: @Bald, мне кажется хотя бы пара слов при цитировании объемного материала в ответе - необходима. Типа "я всегда делаю так как в этой статье", или "я почти не в теме но погуглил за вас и вот что нашел" (это кстати случай из ответа). Без этих пары слов для меня такие ответы мало отличаются от ответа голой ссылкой.