# Нужно ли давать ответ отдельным сообщением, когда автору вопроса хватило комментария?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ответы, неотвеченные-вопросы

Фактически, ответ на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621062/176217) получен в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621062/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-visual-studio-2013#comment863334_621062) в виде ссылки. Что подтверждено ТС отдельным комментарием. Понятно, что если бы ссылка вела на другой вопрос ruSO, текущий можно было закрыть как дубликат. Если на enSO, имело бы смысл сделать перевод на русский и дать отдельным ответом, в том числе, для развития [механизма ассоциации вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/176217). В данном случае ссылка ведет на справочную статью msdn, где для получения [русскоязычной версии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms165394.aspx) достаточно немного изменить URL.

Для того чтобы вопрос как минимум не остался висеть в списке неотвеченных нужно дать ответ. Но каким должен быть такой ответ?

Comment: предположу что краткой выжимки со ссылкой на более подробную информацию может быть достаточно, если же есть возможность/желание то идеальным вариантом может быть публикация подробного пошагового примера

Comment: @Bald получать ответы в комментариях ещё интереснее, когда вопрос именно об ответах в комментариях :)

Comment: просто я не считаю что моего комментария достаточно для публикации полноценного ответа

Comment: связанный: [Репутация за комментарии](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2320/186999)

Comment: @Grundy с одной стороны согласен про дубликат, с другой - тут речь об ответах-ссылках, т.к. полноценный ответ в комментарий просто не поместится. И на этот счёт я нашёл [такой вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2349/176217). См. п.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Написание полноценного ответа нужно -- и не только системе для отчётности, но и сообществу на случай, когда ссылки протухнут. И с msdn это случалось и с документацией IBM.

Хорошая практика, когда в комментариях уточняют вопрос топикстартера, а не пытаются угадать проблему и дать свою версию ответа, а там глядишь повезёт.

Также мы [уже обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4578/213987), что старички не всегда доводят комментарий до полноценного ответа:

> Как правило старичкам просто надоедает в 100500й раз отвечать на
>   легкие вопросы и они отделываются ссылками на дубликаты и кратким
>   комментарием. Потом иногда прибегает новичок, отвечает полно и
>   получает заслуженную карму. А иногда не прибегает и вопрос остается
>   без ответа.

и ещё там же:

> Ответ в комментариях означает, что тот, кто его дал - не считает его
>   ответом. Фактически, это приглашение любому знакомому с темой новичку
>   написать подробный ответ и получить за это репутацию.

Поэтому вполне нормально, если найдётся кто-то, кто захочет дописать полноценный ответ и получить за потраченные усилия немного репутации.

У меня например, не заржавеет поставить плюс хорошо переведённому ответу, если он попадётся мне на глаза. Думаю, так же поступят и многие другие.

Объем ответа -- уже на совести отвечающего. Чем подробнее ответ -- тем больше шансов быть заплюсованным. Можно оставлять и краткую выжимку, чтобы не упираться в проблему [полного заимствования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4612/).

Comment: В упомянутом случае перевод не нужен, он по сути и так есть, достаточно немного изменить URL. Может быть только если сделать какую-то более краткую выжимку из msdn.

Comment: @alexolut Дополнил ответ и таким вариантом. Плюс, замечу что не всякий url в msdn можно так русифицировать, а некоторые разделы вообще не имеют перевода. Лично мне обычно хочется, чтобы в ответе был указан заголовок статьи: во-первых, он меняется реже, а во-вторых именно его обычно потом будешь гуглить в поисковиках.

Comment: @alexolut в некоторых случаях все таки перевод(корректировка) нужен, так как машинный перевод

Comment: @Bald даже машинный перевод MS вполне понятен. Это вам не описание товаров на алиэкспресс :)

Comment: @alexolut понятен-то понятен, но там частенько пропадает отрицание. Будь моя воля - я бы запретил ссылки на русский msdn как вредоносные...