# Что делать с вопросами и ответами, переведёнными машинным способом?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Мы уже неоднократно обсуждали перевод на русский язык вопросов с англоязычных сайтов SE. Основные выводы такие:

- Это хорошо и полезно для сайта.
- Переводчик вкладывает свой труд, поэтому репутация заслуженная. Переводчик не обязан отмечать вопрос как "общий".

А что делать, если вопрос или ответ был переведён машинным способом, т.е. усилия переводчика сводятся к двукратному [Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4612/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#comment16470_4625)?

---

Сегодня я столкнулся с [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623285/181472), который явно переведён Google Translate. Смотрите, вот текст из оригинального вопроса, форматирование сохранено:

> - Without `std::sort(data, data + arraySize);`, the code runs in 11.54 seconds.
> - With the sorted data, the code runs in 1.93 seconds.

Вот что получится, если [перевести его в Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#de/ru/Without%20std%3A%3Asort(data%2C%20data%20%2B%20arraySize)%3B%2C%20the%20code%20runs%20in%2011.54%20seconds.%0A%20%20%20%20With%20the%20sorted%20data%2C%20the%20code%20runs%20in%201.93%20seconds.):

> Без станд :: Sort (данные, данные + ArraySize); код запускается в 11:54 секунд.
>        С отсортированных данных, код выполняется в 1,93 секунды.

А вот текст «перевода»:

> Без станд :: Sort (данные, данные + ArraySize);, код выполняется в 11,54 секунды. С отсортированных данных, код выполняется в 1,93 секунды.

Заметили различие? Буква «ы»! Наш «автор» даже не заметил, что часть внутристрочного кода стала словом!

---

Для справки: вот комментарий за пару дней до переноса ответов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно сделать вопрос общим и отредактировать. Либо написать свой вопрос и объединить с текущим чтобы перенеслись ответы

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если перевод действительно испортил вопрос - вырезаны комментарии, перевод полностью автоматический, после google translate внесены минимальные изменения, часть текста просто выброшена - то

1. Перевести нормально, с сохранением всего ценного.
2. Отметить кривой перевод как дубликат.
3. Слить вопросы в направлении нормального перевода. Это перенесет ответы с сохранением рейтинга.
4. (опционально) поругать автора машинного перевода за вандализм.

Comment: Если кто-то сделает нормальный перевод - скажите, я тут же проведу слияние

Comment: Воспользуюсь возможностью ТСа ставить зелёную галку по собственному усмотрению. ))

Comment: @PashaPash в том то и дело, что перевод не полностью автоматический. Вы просто украли хороший вопрос. Украли мои старания. Изменили один символ и присвоили вопрос себе.

Comment: @AndreyYanov во первых, *себе* я ничего не присваивал. Во вторых - один символ изменили именно вы. Вы пришли на enSO, взяли оттуда топовый вопрос, впейстили его в гугл-транслейт, и запостили на ruSO. После этого вырезали вообще все, что не осилил гугл, оставили вопросе мусор, и активно сопротивлялись вставке ссылки на оригинал (как того требует лицензия на enSO). То, что вы сделали - это вандализм. Пожалуйста, не делайте так больше.

Comment: @PashaPash  вы без предупреждения украли мой вопрос и теперь еще меня оскорбляете. Это недостойное поведение. Как я могу пожаловаться вашим работодателям?

Comment: @AndreyYanov пожаловаться-то вы [можете](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact), но эффекта не будет. Вас вообще-то три дня предупреждали.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если я всё правильно понимаю, *работодатель* PashaPash находится где-то в Минске и будет очень удивлён, получив жалобу подобного рода.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос заблокировать (в том числе для голосования, если это возможно). Связаться с "автором" для выяснения его позиции по этому поводу, может быть он просто хотел таким странным образом получить ответ на русском языке. Предложить ему перевести вопрос нормально. Если отказывается или не может, сделать вопрос общим. Если в первом (машинном) переводе не была указана ссылка на первоисточник, то сразу делать вопрос общим без обсуждения с ТС. Начиная вопрос с плагиата он сам себе подписывает подобный приговор.
После того, как вопрос сделан "общим", перевести самостоятельно или оставить комментарий для разрешения перевода другими участниками. В принципе наличие статуса "общего" уже должно быть достаточно, но так будет очевиднее.

Альтернативный вариант - запретить правилами публикацию переводов вопроса без одновременной публикации ответа. Так будет сложнее не заметить машинный перевод. В данном случае задержка с определением не чистого на руку ТС возникла из-за того, что в вопросе не так много текста для перевода (бОльшая часть - код) и Google справился с ним достаточно хорошо. При этом стоит заметить, что другие предложения "автор" всё же несколько более существенно подкорректировал после машинного перевода. Т.е. нельзя на самом деле утверждать, что это чистой воды копипаст+гугл.транслейт.

Comment: Не уверен, что я как модератор вправе произвольно сделать вопрос общим. На это нужны чёткие правила сообщества, прописанные в справке. Впрочем, я за то, чтобы сформулировать такие правила и справку дополнить.

Comment: "автор" почти ничего не корректировал. Там там и осталось " компилятор аномалией". То, с чем автоперевод не справился, автор просто выбросил

Comment: `запретить правилами публикацию переводов вопроса без одновременной публикации ответа` – да, иначе это слишком легкий способ фармить репу.

Comment: @alexolut со мной никто не связался. Просто украли вопрос. И вы правы - это не копипаст с гугл транслейт. Силы я вкладывал. Но видимо, модераторам не давал покоя популярный вопрос и они захотели его просто украсть. ИМХО, я вижу в этой ситуации лишь рейдерский захват вопроса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не считаю, что такое действие оправдано. Пусть переводят. У нас цель не блокировать набор репутации, а создавать базу вопросов-ответов. Если человек создал нормальный перевод и выложил ответ, то отлично. Если перевод не нормальный — это уже дело сообщества найти и исправить ситуацию.

Comment: @alexolut Создавайте, пожалуйста, два отдельных ответа при наличии альтернативных вариантов для упрощения голосования.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev имхо, это не тот случай, когда ответ с максимальным количеством голосов будет принят единственно верным для сообщества. Поэтому и в разделении особого смысла не вижу. Более того, каждый вариант представляет из себя набор более мелких действий, которые могут как понравиться, так и не понравиться кому-то. Чтобы на всё это натянуть голосование, ответ пришлось бы разбить и вовсе штук на десять.

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто отредактировать и ничего не делать с автором, с его вопросом и т.д. Там же по сути одно предложение искажено. Списать на банальную невнимательность, которая свойственна очень многим.

Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, о чём тут стоит вообще дискутировать, так как не вижу ничего зазорного в ошибке по невнимательности (которая решается небольшой правкой или комментарием-просьбой, если лень самому править) и не понимаю почему автора следует лишать репутации за небольшую невнимательность (за счёт того, что вопрос принудительно делается общим).

Comment: Посмотрите историю правок. [В третьей вырезаны все комментарии из кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/623285/revisions). Сложно такое сделать по банальной невнимательности. Это было сознательное действие.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Может вас удивит моё мнение, но именно удаление этих комментратиев — имхо, совсем некритично, так как они нельзя сказать, что сильно облегчают понимание. Я их даже не заметил в оригинале. Код и без них читается хорошо. И его к тому же немного. Не используются какие-то нетривиальные приёмы и т.д. Без них явно не стало хуже (то есть польза, если и есть, то она незначительна).

Comment: Я плохо знаю плюсы, мне эти комментарии помогли понять суть происходящего в коде. (Минус не мой, если что.)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov спасибо за поддержку, но видимо админы просто хотели украсть хороший вопрос и не придумали ничего лучшего, как сделать вот такое.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov просто захватили вопрос без предупреждения. Нагло украли. А вам за адекватный ответ еще и минус поставили.

Answer (score -2):

Круто, из-за ошибки украсть вопрос. Все с вами ясно. Статья про вас https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/. Я вижу здесь рейдерский захват вопроса из-за одной опечатки. Видимо, здесь место лишь привилегированным тролям, а не нормальным людям, которые хотят развить сообщество за счет полезного контента.

*Сайты Stack Exchange объявлены местом «бесплатного и открытого» обмена информацией, но в действительности они захвачены некоторым небольшим количеством участников, которые просто пытаются получить оценочные баллы, «бейджики» и статус модератора, желая выступать «экспертами» и претендовать на удалённую работу.*

Comment: Вы серьезно считаете, что кто-то позарился на вашу репу?

Comment: Что значит `украли вопрос`?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper изначально я перевел данный вопрос ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626264, а его украли и задали близкие к модераторам люди, чтобы им присвоить рейтинг. Хотя, скорее всего меня за правду сейчас просто заминусуют и забанят.

Comment: Не впадайте в истерику, давайте разбираться. Может вышло недоразумение а вы сейчас такими обвинениями только повышаете градус.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper самое смешное, что сделали это из-за опечатки, которую я допустил. Аргументировали тем, что я тупо перевел его в гугл транслейт ради рейтинга, хотя это наглая ложь и клевета.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, а что разбираться? Вопрос уже украли. Жду бан за правду.

Comment: тем не менее вы должны согласится, что переводить чужой вопрос без соответствующей ссылки не хорошо?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper ссылка есть же. Дело в другом.

Comment: Где этот вопрос? Хочу сам посмотреть.

Comment: @avp http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626264/Почему-отсортированный-массив-обрабатывается-быстрее-чем-не-отсортированный

Comment: @avp его уже слили.

Comment: @AndreyYanov всмысле ссылка есть? Т.е. в вашем вопросе было упоминание о том, что это перевод с указанием источника?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper да. Указал потом. Меня обвиняют за то, что я якобы не приложил усилий на перевод и лишь скопипастил перевод с переводчика.

Comment: @avp ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626264 - это уже украденный вопрос. Мой удален.

Comment: Если все действительно так как вы говорите, то это совсем нехорошо.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper так и есть. Стоит просто прочитать сам вопрос. Из-за небольшой оплошности просто украли вопрос без предупреждения.

Comment: С этим 626264 imho все ОК. Удаленный как-то можно посмотреть?

Comment: @avp разве что через кеш гугла webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QEVkcUHkC64J:ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623285/

Comment: @avp http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623285/Почему-быстрее-обработать-отсортированный-массив-чем-несортированный

Comment: Нашел. В самом деле `Без станд :: Sort (данные, данные + ArraySize);` совсем криво. А что не отредактировали, когда кто-то внимание обратил? Или не сообщили? Правда, остальной перевод тоже не везде естественный для "русского уха",  можно было бы и поредактировать. Но, в принципе, реакция на машинный перевод понятна.

Comment: В очередной раз предлагаю не пороть горячку, а взять перерыв и вернуться к вопросу позже. Поверьте это будет намного полезнее и позволит избежать возможных обид. Сейчас в вас говорят эмоции и вы можете наговорить много лишнего о чем в последствии будете жалеть. То, что тут явно не запрещены обсуждения действий администрации уже говорит о многом. Прекрасно понимаю, что вы своим вопросом хотели помочь сообществу. То, что уйти громко хлопнув дверью выход только кажется.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/626264/revisions - там, кроме "небольшой оплошности" была еще война правок с вырезаниями ссылки на оригинал и вычищение комментов из кода (в 3-й ревизии) вместо того, чтобы перевести их.

Comment: @avp ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @PashaPash, т.е. ТС, хотя ему явно указывали на недостатки, упорно не желал довести текст до ума?

Comment: @PashaPash То, что вопрос переведен плохо и так понятно. Но так ли нужны были эти комментарии для понимания текста? 
Ведь несмотря на всю шероховатость текста отвечающие вопрос поняли.  
Человек приложил свои усилия, пытался сделать *свой* вклад в сообщество. 
Пусть неумело, но он только учится. 
Вместо того, чтобы подсказать, указать на ошибки, подсказать как лучше ответить сообщество ответило агрессивно - "забрало" 
вопрос (очевидно, что дело тут совсем не в  репутации).

Comment: @PashaPash Что мешало дать автору 1-2 дня на исправление (хотя тут исправлять толком нечего) очевидных ошибок?
Представьте, если бы SO на английском блокировали вопросы из-за плохого английского :)

О том, что автору перевода не все равно говорит уже факт оставленного сообщения и добавление в вопрос ссылки
на перевод.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper ему дали 1-2 дня на исправление. Ник оставил замечание  о гуглтранслейте 2017-02-08 10:24:52Z. Создал обсуждение на мете. Слил вопросы в 2017-02-10 15:34:32Z. Это больше двух суток. Andrey Yanov был на сайте 8, 9 и 10-го числа. Но не отреагировал. Вопрос снесли чтобы не поощрять переводы с ухудшением качества.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Я понимаю, что ситуация неоднозначная. Переводы - вообще потенциально проблемные вопросы - мне пару дней назад пришлось откатывать ревизию, где Andrey вырезал ссылку на оригинал. И подчищать комменты вроде "упер вопрос с enSO!" к первой версии перевода. И успокаивать автора этого коммента в чате.

Comment: @avp примерно так. возможно, он просто не успел этого сделать (хотя двух дней должно было хватить)

Comment: @AndreyYanov Ваш вопрос "украли" из-за того, что вы не отреагировали вовремя. Поймите, перевод популярного вопроса привлекает внимание. На любые признаки "автоперевода" или выбрасывания частей оригинала люди начинают реагировать минусами и злобными комментариями. Т.е. варианта "оставить как есть" у модератора не было. Был вариант "украсть" (попросить другого участника сделать новый перевод) или "сделать общим" (что точно так же забрало бы у вас репутацию с новых плюсов, а после правок других участников - забрало бы и имя под вопросом - как произошло с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/

Comment: @AndreyYanov т.к. новый перевод значительно отличается от вашего - там даже комментарии переведены - модератор выбрал первый вариант. Насчет репутации - не заморачивайтесь, она набегает очень быстро, и, в основном, с обычных вопросов и ответов, а не с переводов.

Comment: @PashaPash вы пишите `ему дали 1-2 дня на исправление. Ник оставил замечание о гуглтранслейте 2017-02-08 10:24:52Z. Создал обсуждение на мете.` а вы уверены, что автор получил уведомление о повышенном внимание к его вопросу? Не все пользователи SO просматривают мету. В каком виде было оставлено замечание? Если это было что-то вроде желтой карточки, мол, "Ай-ай-ай, так делать не хорошо" то тут не очевидны последствия для вопроса и непосредственно автора.

Comment: Исходя из того, что решение (т.е. непосредственно что делать) было принято только `вчера` :  `Воспользуюсь возможностью ТСа ставить зелёную галку по собственному усмотрению. )) – Nick Volynkin♦ 21 час назад ` можно сделать вывод о том, что автора о `конкретных` последствиях никто не предупреждал.

Comment: К тому-же из комментариев автора к другим ответам : `@alexolut со мной никто не связался.` и `захватили вопрос без предупреждения.` – Andrey Yanov

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Мету читают не все, но есть общие для всех правила, которые нужно соблюдать сразу, а не после персонального уведомления: 1) плагиат недопустим 2) вопросы должны быть осмысленными и понятными. Вопрос, переведённый гугл-транслейтом и скопированный без указания авторства, нужно было сразу заметить и удалить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin т.о. предупреждения не было?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper я оставлял два комментария с интервалом в сутки примерно. Там была ссылка на этот вопрос на Мете. После объединения я их удалил просто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно узнать текст этих комментариев?

Comment: @Andrey Yanov, Не обижайтесь, не уходите. Оставайтесь, вносите свой посильный вклад в развитие этого сообщества. Обсуждаемый случай не повод останавливаться и сдаваться. Поймите сообщество в общем и администрация в частности готовы идти на диалог. А это всегда замечательно. Заявить о проблеме легко, исправить её намного сложнее. Вместо того, чтобы писать абсолютно не конструктивные ответы, подумайте что можно сделать чтобы такие истории в дальнейшем не повторялись. От того, что вы уйдете лучше никому не будет. Поэтому, как говаривал один умный кот "Ребята, давайте жить дружно" (c)

Comment: @PashaPash если вы хотели реакции, нужно было создать чат и написать мне туда. А не кидать замечания в комментариях, на которые я не успех отреагировать из-за того, что в те дни было много работы и я заходил на сайт лишь для того, чтобы узнать ответ на какую-то проблему. Вы могли бы это видеть хотя бы потому, что в эти дни я не писал активно ответы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предупреждения не было. И только это уже все поясняет.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper после этой ситуации даже не знаю, что делать. Дело не в рейтинге или виртуальных наградах. Дело в отношении. Обидно просто по-человечески, что из-за виртуальных наград люди готовы на такие гадости. Не предупредив, удалять твой труд и присваивать его себе

Comment: @AndreyYanov "удалять твой труд и присваивать его себе" - Grundy **не присваивал себе ваш труд**. Это достаточно легко проверить - [вот вам Gist с вашей и с текущей версиями, посмотрите diff](https://gist.github.com/PashaPash/9b39fde6fae829c11235a298e9776dc7/revisions). Очевидно, что Grundy не "подправил" ваш перевод, он перевел с нуля, причем намного качественнее, Без "просто генерируется" и "С отсортированных данных". Максимум, в чем вы можете обвинить его и Ника - в том, что они "присвоили" себе вашу идею перевести конкретно этот вопрос с enSO.

Comment: @AndreyYanov кстати, уведомления из чата доходят хуже, чем уведомления о комментариях к вопросам.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper добавил скриншот комментария в вопрос.